# Problems with 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS upgrade

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, zeitgeist

I decided to upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. I used `do-release-upgrade`. Everything worked.

When I run `lsb_release -a` I get :

```
Description : Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release :     14.04
Codename :    trusty
```

I think at this moment, the upgrade is a success. But, I have these problems :

1. There's a loop when I try to login to my desktop session. `cat ~/.xsession-errors` gave me :

   ```
   Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
   ```

   On LightDM I still see Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
2. I cannot install anything that could help me solve the problem above. When I run `apt-get -f install` I get :

   ```
   ...
   The following extra packages will be installed:
     ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
     ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
   ...
   E: Could not open file descriptor -1
   ...
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
   ```

When I try `apt-get upgrade`, it asks me at the end to run `apt-get -f install`.

(How) can this be fixed?

**Update**

To resolve the second issue, I proceeded this way : `mv /etc/update-manager/release-upgrade /etc/update-manager/release-upgrade.back` then `dpkg -i --force-overwrite ubuntu-release-upgrader-core*.deb` . At last, `apt-get -f install` worked. Now the challenge will be the desktop access.

Comment: To resolve the seond issue, I proceeded this way : `mv /etc/update-manager/release-upgrade /etc/update-manager/release-upgrade.back` then `dpkg -i --force-overwrite ubuntu-release-upgrader-core*.deb` . At last, `apt-get -f install` worked. Now the challenge will be the desktop access.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the second issue, I proceeded this way :

```
sudo mv /etc/update-manager/release-upgrade{,.back}
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite ubuntu-release-upgrader-core*.deb
```

At last, `sudo apt-get -f install` worked.

I ran

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After reboot, to solve the problem `Failed To Start Session`. I followed the first part of the solution proposed here [ItsFOSS](http://itsfoss.com/failed-to-start-session-ubuntu-14-04/).

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

The next step was a problem with Unity not properly loading. This topic was already discussed here: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Finally I uninstalled Unity and installed Gnome Shell.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```